# How to load website on mobile devices automatically in fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, mobile, fullscreen

When you open google.com/maps on a mobile device (at least in Chrome), you'll see the website loading in fullscreen. However, the system bar with the time, etc. is still visible on top, but with the website taking the whole space.

How can this be accomplished? When I try entering fullscreen mode with JS without any user interaction, it fails.

I tried `if(confirm('Go fullscreen?')) document.documentElement.requestFullscreen()` but this doesn't seem to count as a user interaction that would justify going into fullscreen...

```js
if (confirm('Go fullscreen?'))
  document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
```